# How to return a array into a matrix index in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

Here is what I have:

```
coluna = zeros(2,3);
coluna(1) = func(3,2,1);
coluna(2) = func(3,4,5);
```

Here is example of the function:

```
function vec = func(a,b,c)
    vec = zeros(3,1);
    vec(1,1) = a*b*c;
    vec(2,1) = a+b+c;
    vec(3,1) = a-b-c;
end
```

This is only an example code, but it illustrate pretty much everything I mean by the problem.

In C++ lets say it would be like this:

```
int *func(int a,int b,int c){
    int vet[2];
    vet[0]=a*b*c;
    vet[1]=a+b+c;
    vet[2]=a-b-c;
    return vet;
}

int main(){
    int mat[1][2];
    mat[0]=func(3,2,1);
    mat[1]=func(3,4,5);
}
```

In MatLab it will give me this error:

> In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same.

How may I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this occurs is because you are doing this:

```
coluna(1) = ...
```

When you want to assign a row of an array you need to do this:

```
coluna(1, :) = ...
```

similarly for a column:

```
 coluna(:, 1) = ...
```

Then you need to make sure the return from `func` is the same size as the thing you are replacing.

So in your example, this is the correct way to assign the output from `func`:

```
coluna = zeros(2,3);
coluna(1, :) = func(3,2,1);
coluna(2, :) = func(3,4,5);
```